# publish selenium reports from jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, maven-2

I run selenium scripts through maven.Please let me know how to publish selenium reports under post build actions in jenkins.I tried several options

Publish selenium report
publish selenium html report
publish HTML report
publish test ng reports

I tried giving full path from C drive where the surefire reports exist
C:\proj1\target\surefire-reports*.html

it says file *.html doesn't exist
and for html report-it says no report exist 
tried giving workspace relative path as well but it provides empty report
In test results folder in excel sheet,I get the report the status of each testcase.But its not published in jenkins.
Could anyone please send me the exact tried out steps to publish reports from jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Publushing report with the publishHTML reports works with the repository. You should not type the file path

For example, I have on my projects the following as the endpoint for reports.

```
WebContent/build/Selenium/resultsTests/
```

Where of course resultsTests is my directory where I publish my reports.

Here is a screenshot of my config

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder inside your job/workspace folder.
Example my job folder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Yahoo\workspace`. 
I created a folder named results 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Yahoo\workspace\results`.
I set Test Report HTMLs as `results/`.
You can check on the link right below the folder field:
`Basedir of the fileset is the workspace root`. <--- "The workspace root" is a link to your workspace so you can see your new folder there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

- install html publisher plugin in your jenkins and restart post done
- from your framework copy the path of the folder where reports are getting saved.
  Example my path is : D:\workspace\rule\CurrentTestResult
- In your Jenkins job, navigate to Post -build actions
- In section "HTML directory to archive" give above path
  Example : "**D:\workspace\rule\CurrentTestResult**"
- And in index page[s],  mention your file name, Or simply add "***.html**"
- In report title give any desired name
- Apply and check